Github ActionsでFlutterのCI/CDでaabのビルドでエラーになります
以下のサイトを参考に、サンプルアプリを使用してCI/CDの動作確認をしています。
GitHub Actionsを使って、Androidアプリのリリースを自動化する - Qiita
AABのビルドでエラーになっています。
Run ./android/gradlew :app:bundleRelease
/home/runner/work/_temp/5a49113d-ef20-49da-969a-478d3a5d7b34.sh: line 1: ./android/gradlew: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

実際のところ、ローカルリポジトリにgradlewはありますが、gitignoreによりリモートリポジトリには入っていません。
ignoreファイルを編集してアップロードさせるべきでしょうか？
もしくは、Workflowのファイルに何か付け加えるべきでしょうか？
対応方法等教えていただけると助かります。
Workflowのyamlは以下の通りです。
name: Flutter CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.24.5'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Analyze code
        run: flutter analyze

      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test

      # キーストア設定
      # シークレットファイル配置用のディレクトリ作成
      - name: Create secrets directory
        run: |
          mkdir secrets
      # キーストアファイルをBase64からデコードしてファイルとして配置
      - name: Decode Keystore
        run: echo '${{ secrets.ENCODED_RELEASE_KEYSTORE }}' | base64 --decode > playstore.keystore
      # デコードしたキーストアファイルをsecretsディレクトリ下に配置
      - name: Copy Keystore
        run: |
          cp playstore.keystore secrets/playstore.keystore

      # aabファイルを生成
      - name: Generate AAB
        run: |
          ./android/gradlew :app:bundleRelease
        env:
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS }}
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD }}
          KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD }}

Generate AABの箇所を以下のように修正してみました。
      - name: Generate AAB
        run: |
          ./android/gradlew init
          ./android/gradlew :app:bundleRelease
        env:
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS }}
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD }}
          KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD }}

ですが、以下のエラーになりました。
* What went wrong:
Cannot locate tasks that match ':app:bundleRelease' as project 'app' not found in root project 'githubactions_mobileapps_test'.

以下のコマンドをローカルで実行するとビルドは成功しています。
./gradlew :app:bundleRelease


最終的に以下の内容で、ビルドは通るようになりました。
ただ、ビルドの後Playストアに上げるところでビルドしたファイルが見つからないエラーに遭っています。
別で質問するので、意見もらえると助かります。
name: Flutter CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.24.5'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Create local.properties
        run: |
          echo "flutter.sdk=$HOME/flutter" > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/local.properties
          echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" >> $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/local.properties

      - name: Analyze code
        run: flutter analyze

      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test

      - name: Create secrets directory
        run: mkdir -p $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/app/secrets

      # キーストアファイルをBase64からデコードしてファイルとして配置
      - name: Decode Keystore
        run: echo '${{ secrets.ENCODED_RELEASE_KEYSTORE }}' | base64 --decode > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/android/app/secrets/playstore.keystore

      # aabファイルを生成
      - name: Generate AAB
        run: ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease --console=plain
        working-directory: android
        env:
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS }}
          KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD }}
          KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.RELEASE_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD }}

